# Mistake again? Verifying ZFNet layers' input-output dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

As mentioned in one of the lecture of [cs231n](http://cs231n.github.io/), there were some calculation errors in [AlexNet](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks) architecture. The initial size of the image has to be `227x227` instead of `224x224` which is what is mentioned in the paper. I wanted to know is there any similar problem in the paper of ZFNet as well? [image]

In the given figure (from [ZFNet paper](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf)) the initial size of the image is again `224x224` so if we will use a 2D convolution layer with 96 filters of size `(7x7)` and stride `(2,2)` then the size of the result should be `(224-7)/2 + 1 = 109.5` but if we take initial image size to be `225x225` then we will exactly get `110`. Moreover, in the first layer, I feel that there is a similar problem. The size of input to max-pool layer is `110x110x96` and pooling size is `(3x3)` with stride `2`, so the size of the output should be `(110-3)/2 + 1 = 54.5` which is again not an integer. I want to know am I doing right calculations or is there any problem with the values given in the paper?

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch built-in implementation says that you need to use padding:

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 96, 7, stride=2, padding=2)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(96, 256, 5, padding=2)
self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(256, 384, 3, padding=1)
self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(384, 384, 3, padding=1)
self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(384, 256, 3, padding=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you are using zf net architure diagram zf net is similiar to alexnet but have a filter smaller filter size of 7*7 with stride of 2 there is no calucalation error it just round up the values.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).